# Input field strange behaviour in Firefox (transparent text)

Tags: css, firefox

my website http://thatmp3.com/ works perfectly on chrome/IE and all the other browers except for Firefox which somehow shows white text on the white input field, as well as transparent placeholder, transparent highlighting, as if the user isn't typing anything in the search input however if I blindly select and copy the text then paste it, it works so it's a matter of colors or z-index. I tried everything but nothing shows up on the input bar... Can you please help?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that the website's CSS is very tangled and I don't know what's causing the problem... I'll try to post everything related to the element but i'm not sure if it'll be sufficient...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in setting a height on the input of `40px` and also padding of `50px`. That is pushing the placeholder text out of view. I would suggest removing the height and instead setting a line height. You'll have to make a few other adjustments too.

```
.search {
  height: 40px;  /* remove, and try line-height instead */
  padding: 25px 50px; /* adjust */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This css works;

```
.search {
border: 0 none;
border-radius: 2px;
box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgb(139, 139, 139);
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
font-family: Roboto;
font-weight: 300;
line-height: 47px;padding-right:100px;
margin-top: 15px;
outline: medium none;
text-indent: 46px;
width: 100%;
```

}